# Why do I SignatureDoesNotMatch error whilst saving thumbnail urls with firebase storage cloud storage triggers?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I am using firebase resize extension which, when original picture is uploaded, it resizes it and creates another picture in that folder with renamed version -
**user1profile => user1profile_320x320**

I wrote a trigger function, that once the resized thumbnail is created, I generate url and update my documents in firestore:

```
        const isThumbnail = object.name.endsWith("_320x320");

        const signedURLconfig = {
          action: "read" as const,
          expires: "03-09-2491",
        };

        const signedURLArray = await file.getSignedUrl(signedURLconfig);
        const url = signedURLArray[0];

        if (folder == "profilePhotos" && isThumbnail) {
          const userPublicRef = db.collection("usersPublic").doc(userId);
          const usersPrivateRef = db.collection("users").doc(userId);

          batch.set(userPublicRef, { profilePhoto: url }, { merge: true });
          batch.set(usersPrivateRef, { profilePhoto: url }, { merge: true });

          await batch.commit();
```

Strangely, everything works for few days, but after some time I can't access these thumbnails for my app anymore, even though it shouldn't expire.

1. What is causing this issue and how can I fix it?
2. Why do I have to provide expiration date, I want my pictures to be accessible.
3. Why are signed urls are so long compared to the ones that I create from the client with  **getDownloadURL()**?

Answer (score 1):

> What is causing this issue and how can I fix it?

The Signed URLs are expiring. After the expiration date, the object is not accessible via the Signed URL.

> Why do I have to provide expiration date, I want my pictures to be
> accessible.

Signed URLs expire. The maximum time is 604,800 seconds (7 days).

> Why are signed urls are so long compared to the ones that I create
> from the client with getDownloadURL()?

Signed URLs have authorization parameters. Those parameters are large data objects.

If you do not want URLs to expired, then you cannot use Signed URLs. In that case, set the access for the Cloud Storage object to public read-only.

[Google Cloud Storage Signed URLs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls)

[Google Cloud Storage: Overview of Access Control](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control)

Comment: Since, resizing happens on the server, how would I access that download url and attach it to my firestore document?

Comment: @Ripas55 - That is a different question. Please post a new question.